# There appears to be a bug in my XOR encryption program written in python

Tags: python, encryption, xor

I have been trying to write a simple encryption program in Python, and when I try to execute the code on Linux, it is not printing anything. Could someone please tell me why?

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python2
import binascii
def encrypt():
    text = raw_input("Please input your information to encrypt: ")
    for i in text:
        #Convert text into a binary sequence
        i = bin(int(binascii.hexlify(i),16))
    key = raw_input("Please input your key for decryption: ")
    for j in key:
        #Convert key into a binary sequence
        j = bin(int(binascii.hexlify(j),16))
    #This is only here for developmental purposes
    print key
    print text
```

**Edit**
I did what one of the users said, but my code still does not seem to be converting my plain text into binary like I want it too.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
def encrypt():
    text = raw_input("Please input your information to encrypt: ")
    for i in text:
        #Convert text into a binary sequence
        i = bin(ord(i))
    key = raw_input("Please input your key for decryption: ")
    for j in key:
        #Convert key into a binary sequence
        j = bin(ord(j))
    #This is only here for developmental purposes
    print key
    print text

encrypt()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of major problems with your program:

1. You are defining a function called `encrypt()`, but never calling it.
2. Neither of your loops actually modifies the string. They modify loop variables, which are not the same thing!
3. `int(binascii.hexlify(x), 16)` is an overcomplicated way of writing `ord(x)`.
4. `bin()` does not do what you are hoping for here.
5. Nothing is actually being XORed here. Your program is unfinished.

Comment: I had never actually said it was a finished program.
With the ord, is there a library I have to import?

Comment: Nope. `ord()` is a builtin.

Comment: I read up on what Ord() does, and it is not doing what I want it to do. I am wanting to convert plain text / Ascii into a binary sequence to make it easier to XOR.

Comment: @user2603709: The combination of `ord()` and `chr()` will do this job just fine.

Comment: I am not trying to use integers for my output of this function though. This is converting pure text into a decimal.

Comment: Ok, so I see what you're saying about the loop vars, but how do I turn that back into a string?

Comment: Please read the second point of my answer carefully. As written, neither of your loops is actually doing anything. As to the rest, `chr()` is the inverse of `ord()`.

Comment: Plain text **is** a binary sequence (on Python 2).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do

```
def encrypt():
  cleartext = raw_input("Please input your information to encrypt: ")
  ciphertext = []
  for char in cleartext:
    ciphertext.append(bin(ord(char))[2:])
  ciphertext = ''.join(ciphertext)

  key = raw_input("Please input your key for decryption: ")
  decryptionKey = []
  for char in key:
    decryptionKey.append(bin(ord(char))[2:])
  decryptionKey = ''.join(decryptionKey)

  print "The key is '%s'" %decryptionKey
  print "The encrypted text is '%s'" %ciphertext
```

Comment: That is close to what I want to do, except it hasn't been fully encrypted as of yet.

Comment: @user2603709: `it hasn't been fully encrypted as of yet`. Yes, I only did what you've attempted to do in your code. You mentioned in a comment on duskwuff's post that your program was not complete. All I did was implement the features that you have attempted to implement in your post, nothing further

Comment: I was just mentioning the fact that you mentioned ciphered text in there, even thought that wasn't finalized yet.

Comment: @user2603709: granted. Feel free to change the variable name as you wish